# 500 Internal Server Error django + mod_wsgi + apache2 on ubuntu 16

Tags: django, apache2, ubuntu-16.04, mod-wsgi

I am trying to deploy my application on Ubuntu server i have done everything correct as far as i know but i am always getting the 500 internal server issue error.

I have tried so many troubleshooting guides but i cannot find anything useful that ca resolve the issue.
Here is the /etc/apache2/sites-available conf file

```
        Alias /static /home/local/user/wesupportapp/static
        <Directory /home/local/user/wesupportapp/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/local/user/wesupportapp/media
        <Directory /home/local/user/wesupportapp/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

         <Directory /home/local/user/wesupportapp/wesupportapp>

        <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
        </Files>
  </Directory>

  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/local/user/wesupportapp/wesupportapp/wsgi.py
  WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-path=/home/local/user/wesupportapp python-home=/home/local/user/wesupportapp/venv
  WSGIProcessGroup django_app
```

When i run the application on the development server of django everything works well but once i enable the app conf file i have the 500 error.

If someone had the same issue that i am facing that can really help me resolving this it will be so much appreciated.

apache2 error log

```
[Tue Jul 16 10:42:33.386640 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834262898432] [remote 10.72.15.5:3756]   File "/home/local/user/wesupportapp/wesupportapp/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Tue Jul 16 10:42:33.386644 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834262898432] [remote 10.72.15.5:3756]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Jul 16 10:42:33.386692 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834262898432] [remote 10.72.15.5:3756] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[Tue Jul 16 10:47:48.994459 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834212525824] [remote 10.216.63.3:3756] mod_wsgi (pid=6299): Target WSGI script '/home/local/user/wesupportapp/wesupportapp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as P$
[Tue Jul 16 10:47:48.994552 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834212525824] [remote 10.216.63.3:3756] mod_wsgi (pid=6299): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/local/user/wesupportapp/wesupportapp/wsgi.py$
[Tue Jul 16 10:47:48.994706 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834212525824] [remote 10.216.63.3:3756] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jul 16 10:47:48.994734 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834212525824] [remote 10.216.63.3:3756]   File "/home/local/user/wesupportapp/wesupportapp/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Tue Jul 16 10:47:48.994739 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834212525824] [remote 10.216.63.3:3756]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Jul 16 10:47:48.994764 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834212525824] [remote 10.216.63.3:3756] ImportError: No module named 'django'
[Tue Jul 16 11:03:42.242236 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834262898432] [remote 10.216.63.3:684] mod_wsgi (pid=6299): Target WSGI script '/home/local/user/wesupportapp/wesupportapp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Py$
[Tue Jul 16 11:03:42.242345 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834262898432] [remote 10.216.63.3:684] mod_wsgi (pid=6299): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/local/user/wesupportapp/wesupportapp/wsgi.py'.
[Tue Jul 16 11:03:42.242464 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834262898432] [remote 10.216.63.3:684] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Tue Jul 16 11:03:42.242485 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834262898432] [remote 10.216.63.3:684]   File "/home/local/user/wesupportapp/wesupportapp/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Tue Jul 16 11:03:42.242489 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834262898432] [remote 10.216.63.3:684]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Tue Jul 16 11:03:42.242509 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 6299:tid 139834262898432] [remote 10.216.63.3:684] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

Comment: What is in the Apache error log?

Comment: Hi daniel, where can i find it please

Comment: okey i found it i will add it to the question

Comment: I think its running in an environment. If you check your log there it's showing it can't find the django installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, I forget to install Django in the virtual environment. Install Django in this virtual environment

```
/home/local/user/wesupportapp/venv
```

Comment: Hi Pranja, i think it was the issue, i have removed the virtual environment and create a new one and installed django on it, the issue is now resolved.